# How to disable the init movement of Foundation's 6 range sliders during page load?

Tags: jquery, slider, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have about 50 range sliders on a page. These are very lagging because of the init movement of the slider-handles. How to disable this?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I have never found a way to stop the sliding other than disabling the slider.  The problem then is that the slider handle is in the lower limit position even though the value could be properly set. It is another unfortunate issue with F6. I thought you might be able to set the data-start to the same value of your initial-start and then use js to reset the data-start to zero or whatever your lower limit. That would keep the slider from having to move but I have not been able to successfully reset the slider data-start to zero.   (if someone can figure that out maybe it would work?)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove css transitions from slider handle class when you are initialising your slider then restore the transitions on slider value change - this has worked for me so far

For example :

```
function mySliderInit(){

    // remove all transitions
    $(".slider-handle").css({
        transition: 'none'
    });

    // ...code to initialise slider
}

// Initialise slider
mySliderInit();

$(".slider").on("changed.zf.slider", function() {

    // restore transitions as defined in foundation.css
    $(".slider-handle").css({
        transition: ''
    });

    // ...handle slider value change
});
```